# How to name form elements to submit as array in URL?

Tags: html, forms, url

I am creating a page that will allow results to be filtered. I am trying to create a URL that looks something like this, once the form is submitted:

```
/results/filtered?categories=[1,3,5]&types=[7,8,9]
```

I have a form that looks something like this:

```
<form action="/results/filtered" method="get">
  Category filters:
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="1">
  ...
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="5">

  Types:
  ... same sort of thing
  <input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="9">

  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

However, when I submit the form, I'm getting a URL that looks like:

```
/results/filtered?categories%5B%5D=1&categories%5B%5D=3&categories%5B%5D=5&types%5B%5D=7&types%5B%5D=8&types%5B%5D=9
```

It works, but it's pretty ugly. How can I change my form so that I get nice clean URLs?

Comment: what are you submitting the form to?

Comment: @Patricia what do you mean? This form is submitting to a PHP application, but I don't think that's relevant to the solution.

Comment: Your server side technology has to be able to understand what your sending it.  why does what the url looks like matter?

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the format of the url that way unless you create your own form pre-processor using javascript.